# Unicode / UTF Seo Friendly Url (slug) Using Php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, url-rewriting, seo

My Url Change to Seo Friendly using this function + .htaccess . My Project Is in ARABIC Language !

```
function clean($title) {

$seo_st = str_replace(' ', '-', $title);
$seo_alm = str_replace('--', '-', $seo_st);
$title_seo = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $seo_alm));

return $title_seo;}
```

now in my url I see This :

localhost/news/4/�����-��-����-�����-��-����/

What's Problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your code before doing anything else and tell me if it works:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Already on config file. I put all UTF-8 Code in My Config File. But I Dont Know What's Problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$dbconnect = @mysql_connect($server,$db_username,$db_password);
$charset = @mysql_set_charset('utf8',$dbconnect);


<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" /> 
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your database field `collation` is properly set to UTF-8, and that your connection is UTF-8 `SET NAMES "utf8"`.

If you're using any characters from values in your scripts, make sure they're UTF-8 as well.

Comment: in my config : mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); And My collation : utf8_persian_ci

Comment: Debug your chain then, find out when the characters become corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Try it... it works for me

```html
<?php
  function clean_url($text)  
  {      
  $code_entities_match = array(' ','&amp;','--','&quot;','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','+','{','}','|',':','"','<','>','?','[',']','\\',';',"'",',','.','/','*','+','~','`','=','"');  
  $code_entities_replace = array('-','-','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','');  
  $text = str_replace($code_entities_match, $code_entities_replace, $text); 
  return urlencode($text);  
  }  
?>
```